# latex error Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations

Tags: natbib

I'm relatively new to latex and when I try to add references using natbib, I'm getting the following error.

`Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.`

I have looked all the entries in the bib file and none of them has any missing years. I even changing the `bibliographystyle` and nothing worked.
Can anyone help me fix this?

Here is a minimum  working example which reproduces this issue

```
\include{Macros/MacroFile1}

\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{Classes/myThesis}


\linespread{1.3} %1.5 line spacing

\begin{document}
Hello, this is a minimum working example to show the error \cite$
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References} % Adds References to $
\bibliographystyle{nature} % bibliography style
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliography{ref-example.bib}
\end{document}
```

ref-eaxmple.bib

```
@article{fernandez-pacheco_three-dimensional_2017,
    title = {Three dimensional nanomagnetism},
    volume = {8},
    copyright = {2017 The Author(s)},
    issn = {2041-1723},
    url = {https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms15756},
    doi = {10.1038/ncomms15756},
    language = {en},
    number = {1},
    urldate = {2021-06-16},
    journal = {Nature Communications},
    author = {Fernández-Pacheco, Amalio and Streubel, Robert and Fruchart, Olivier and Hertel, Riccardo and Fischer, Peter and Cowburn, Russell P.},
    month = jun,
    year = {2017},
    note = {Number: 1
    Publisher: Nature Publishing Group},
    pages = {15756},
    file = {Full Text PDF:/home/rajgourav/Zotero/storage/N2WSEP79/Fernández-Pacheco et al. - 2017 - Three-dimensional nanomagnetism.pdf:application/pdf;Snapshot:/home/rajgourav/Zotero/storage/AK82XNP5/ncomms15756.html:text/html}
}
```

Comment: unrelated but don't use \include in the preamble. Use \input intead.  Beside this: your bibliographystyle is not compatible with natbib.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me what bibligraphystayle is compatible with natbib?

Comment: https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_bibliography_styles

Comment: Hi,  I want to use the bibliographystyle {naturemag) which pacakge should i unclude for this?